# Solve $\sin(3x)=\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Question: Solve $\sin(3x)=\cos(2x)$ for $0≤x≤2\pi$.

My knowledge on the subject; I know the general identities, compound angle formulas and double angle formulas so I can only apply those.

With that in mind

\begin{align} 
\cos(2x)=&~ \sin(3x)\\
\cos(2x)=&~ \sin(2x+x) \\
\cos(2x)=&~ \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x)\\
\cos(2x)=&~  2\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(x) + \big(1-2\sin^2(x)\big)\sin(x)\\
\cos(2x)=&~  2\sin(x)\cos^2(x) + \sin(x) - 2\sin^2(x)\\
\cos(2x)=&~  2\sin(x)\big(1-\sin^2(x)\big)+\sin(x)-2\sin^2(x)\\
\cos(2x)=&~  2\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)- 2 \sin^2(x)\\
\end{align}
**edit**

\begin{gather}
 2\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)- 2 \sin^2(x) = 1-2\sin^2(x) \\
 2\sin^3(x) - 3\sin(x) + 1 = 0 
\end{gather}

This is a cubic right?

So $u = \sin(x)$,

\begin{gather} 2u^3 - 3u + 1 = 0 \\ 
 (2u^2 + 2u - 1)(u-1) = 0 
\end{gather}

Am I on the right track?
This is where I am stuck what should I do now?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x) = \cos(\pi /2 - x) $ and [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html): $ \sin \alpha - \sin \beta = \ldots $

Comment: @GohP.iHan , I'm afraid I cannot use those.. (school does not allow it)

Comment: you fifth line has an error. It should have $-2\sin^3 x.$

Comment: @AnuragA oh thanks!

Comment: sin x=1 is one solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use $\sin 3x=3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3x$ and $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x$. To get
$$3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3x=1-2\sin^2x.$$
Now call $\sin x=t$. Thus we have
$$4t^3-2t^2-3t+1=0.$$
Observe that $t=1$ is definitely a solution, so we have
$$(t-1)(4t^2+2t-1)=0.$$ 
The quadratic factor will be zero for 
$$t=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$$
I hope you can solve from here.

Answer (score 6):

$$\cos2x=\sin3x=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-3x\right)$$

$$\iff2x=2m\pi\pm\left(\dfrac\pi2-3x\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Alternatively, $$\sin3x=\cos2x=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-2x\right)$$

$$3x=n\pi+(-1)^n\left(\dfrac\pi2-2x\right)$$  where $n$ is any integer

Comment: I like this much better than the accepted solution. Not only is it relatively simple and direct, you get the angle in a "nice" form without having to remember or guess the arc sine of $(-1+\sqrt5)/4.$

Answer (score 1):

You have made some errors in your calculations (or some typos here).

$$\sin(3x)=\cos(2x)$$

$$ \sin(2x+x) = \cos(2x)$$

$$\sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)sin(x) = \cos(2x) $$

$$ 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(x) + (1-2\sin^2(x))\sin(x)) = \cos(2x) $$

$$ 2\sin(x)\cos^2(x) + \sin(x) - 2\sin^{\bf{3}}(x) = \cos(2x) $$

$$ 2\sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x))+\sin(x)-2\sin^{\bf{3}}(x)=\cos(2x) $$

$$ 2\sin(x) - 2\sin^3(x) + \sin(x)- 2 \sin^{\bf{3}}(x) = \cos(2x) $$

$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)=\cos(2x)$$

Then recall that $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$ to give:

$$3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$

This is a cubic in $\sin(x)$. For simplicity write $y=\sin(x)$ to get:

$$-4y^3+2y^2+3y-1=0$$

$$-(y-1)(4y^2+2y-1)=0$$

So $\sin(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$

So $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{10}$, $\frac{9\pi}{10}$, $\frac{13\pi}{10}$, $\frac{17\pi}{10}$